# Convert string with leading zeros to a number

Tags: c#, converters

I've got a bit of a challenge. I have a string which contains of 11 characters, the first 10 denotes an amount, and the last one is a letter or special letter, which represents a value to add.

For example if I got

> 0000000400A

this means

> 400 + 2

So the result should be

> 402

I can't figure out how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: What are the rules governing why A = 2, and what are the possible values in that last character?

Comment: Looks like 10 characters to me.

Comment: I just corrected the number of chars. I got A to D, which respresents the values from 2 to 5.

Comment: You can reduce your problem to the set of smaller problems: 1) get all symbols except for last one from a string 2) parse it as an integer 3) get the last symbol of a string 4) convert it to an integer based on your special requirements 5) add them up

Comment: `int result = int.Parse(source.Substring(0, source.Length - 1)) + source[source.Length - 1] - 'A' + 2`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
// Setup
var dict = new Dictionary<char, int>();
dict.Add('A', 2);
dict.Add('B', 3);
dict.Add('C', 4);
dict.Add('D', 5);

var str = "0000000400A";

// This is what you need
var result = Convert.ToInt32(str.Substring(0, 10)) + dict[str[10]];

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: While this answers the question, you should generally not answer the questions if the author has put no effort and didn't attempt anything. It isn't helpful for other people and it isn't helpful for the author either.

Comment: Okay, i understand, you are right, sorry.

Comment: i don't know why this got up vote . 'Convert.ToInt32(str.Substring(0, 10))' throw exception because it starts with zeros .